# I am trying to return the index position till context-root, is this optimized

Tags: java

This method will take a URl as input and return the position till context root

```
 private static int extractPositionTillContextRootInUrl(String url) {
            int t = 0;
            int i = 0;
            for (; i < url.length(); i++) {
                char charAt = url.charAt(i);
                if (charAt == '/') 
                    t++;
                if (t == 4)
                    break;
            }
            return i;
        }
```

Comment: input:String s="https://www.zzzz.com/a/contextroot/doc.pdf";output:count till contextroot eg index 31

Comment: why? and do you have a question?

Comment: s.indexof("/") does not work ?

Comment: your  question needs clarification please explain it more

Comment: Can any one write a  better version of it

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here, but try `URL urlObj = new URL(url);` Now you can ask the object questions like `urlObj.getHost()` or `urlObj.getPort()`. This will keep your code much cleaner, and bugfree. See more here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

Comment: `s.lastIndexOf("/")` will give you the index of last `/`

Comment: if some one send me  a URL as a String , i need to extract the the String containing address till context root.it will count four slashes and return the index just before 4th slash

Comment: input="https://www.zz.com/contextroot/fax/doc.pdf";   output "https://www.zz.com/contextroot"

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten your for loop to this.

```
int i = 0, t = 0;
for (; i < url.length(); i++) {
    if (url.charAt(i) == '/' && ++t == 4) break;
}
return i;
```

`&&` is short circuiting so `++t == 4` will only run if `url.charAt(i) == '/'` is true.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use a regular expression pattern.
This approach will be a bit slower but it will allow you to check more cases in one go. At first it seems more verbose but if adapted to your need

```
private static final Pattern urlPattern = Pattern.compile("^(http(s?)://).*?/.*?/(.*)$");

private static int extractPositionTillContextRootInUrl(String url) {
    Matcher matcher = urlPattern.matcher(url);
    return matcher.matches() ? matcher.start(3) : -1;
}
```

Another solution would be to use the java.net.URL object

```
private static int extractPositionTillContextRootInUrl(String url) {
        try {
            return new URL(url).getPath().indexOf("/", 1);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```